RDA analysis in R
I'm working with foraminifera diversity in the Arctic on my master thesis. I want to look at how environmental variables are affecting the species variation, so I'm using RDA. This is my code:

library(vegan)

sp = decostand(sp, "hellinger")

rda = rda(sp ~., env)

plot(rda)


I get the correct plot and everything, but the problem is that only 3 environmental variables are shown in the plot and I have 7. I have only samples from 4 stations, so I was thinking that maybe I have to few stations? In total my environmental data have 4 observations with 7 variables and my species data have 4 observations with 29 variables. If anyone could help I would be very grateful.
Best regards,
Endre

It's good that you provide your code but without the data env this is not a minimal reproducible example as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. It's also not clear what's the question that you're asking.
